# bug with django-filebrowser and django-storages which library is at fault?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage, django-filebrowser

I use django-filebrowser and django-storages (w/ s3boto) to add file embed into my tinyMCE implementations for my django projects.

Recently I noticed that there is a bug, django-fileborwser does not save thumbnailed versions of uploaded files properly when using an S3 as a backend.

I stepped through the version creation function (in django-filebrowser), and found what I think to be the bug.

```
fp is at EOF. Use rewind option or seek() to data start.
```

which occurs because

```
# Rewing the file pointer back to 0, before saving to the storage object
tmpfile.seek(0)
```

isn't called before

```
# Existing Code
site.storage.save(version_path, tmpfile)
```

I reported the bug through the issue tracker with my suggested fix. Then the repo's author threw me for a loop and asked:

> @fyaconiello shouldn´t that snippet be part of the s3-storage engine (with django-storages) instaed of adding it to the filebrowser?

1. I guess the file rewind could be done in either library. But which library does it belong in?

   - Should django-storages make sure all tmpfile pointers are rewound?
   - is it django-filebrowser's job as it is the implimentor?

[See my full issue here](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser/issues/103)

Answer (score 0):

They provide a solution here: https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser/issues/40

Comment: that thread solves a different problem. at the very end of the thread you'll notice it links to another issue - mine. https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser/issues/103